# A question about an algebraic notation

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm dealing with this notation and I can not interpret it

> *Let* $f(X)$ $\in$ $F[X]$ *be a monic polynomial of degree* $m$, *and let* $(f)$ *be the ideal generated by* $f$. *Consider the qotient ring* $F[X]/(f(X))$, *and write* $x$ *for the image of* $X$ *in* $F[X]/((f(X))$, *i.e.,* $x$ *is the coset* $X+(f(X))$. *Then:*
>
> *(a) The map*
>
> $\qquad$$\qquad$ $\qquad$$\qquad$ $P(X)\mapsto P(x):F[X]\to F[x]$ $\qquad$ $(*)$
>
> *is a surjective homomorphism in which* $f(X)$ *maps to* $0$. *Therefore,* $f(x)=0$ $\quad$ *(...)*

The notation offending is marked with $(*)$. I believe that the implied operation is that the generic polynomial is in correspondence with the set of polynomials obtained by replacing the indeterminate $X$ of the polynomial with the various elements of $X + (f (X))$, but I am not sure of this interpretation (eg about the effective meaning of the $P$ symbol used).
Kindly, someone could confirm the meaning I have in mind, or explain to me what actually does this mean?

Comment: Have you studied quotient rings and, if so, do you have a good grasp of the basic concepts? If not, you might find it more helpful to pose more general questions about quotient rings.

Comment: @MathGems I have to do a small correction. It's true that basing myself only on the text of Hernstein was impossible to me to understand this meaning, however, the second book (which is more detailed, complete and, in my opinion, organic) effectively contains sufficient information to understand the thing. Although the particular case that I mentioned does not appear, it is possible to deduce the meaning according to the general presentation from the definition of $F[S]$ (I was mistaken, in this book there),

Comment: ...continuing with the evaluation homomorphism theorem, and characterization of simple extensions. But this reading is fresh in my mind for I just finished the book, so, as you've observed, I cannot  have instantly the just learned concepts. Next time I will read more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is using standard (polynomial) functional notation $\,P(X)\,$ to denote an arbitrary element of the polynomial ring $\,F[X].\:$ Then if $\rm\:\alpha\:$ is an element of any ring $\,E\,$ containing $\,F,\,$ the term $\,P(\alpha)\,$ denotes the result of evaluating $\,P(X)\,$ at $\,X = \alpha,\,$ i.e. the image of $\,P(X)\,$ under the unique evaluation homomorphism $\,h\,$ extending the embedding $\,F\to E\,$ with $\, h(X) = \alpha\:$ (the existence and uniquenesss of the evaluation map is the *universal property* of polynomial rings).

Yours is the special case when $\, E = F[X]/(f(X))\,$ and $\ x := \alpha = h(X) = X+(f(X))\:$ is the natural image of $\,X\,$ in the quotient ring $\,E.\,$ It is simply a generalization of the well-known construction of $\:\Bbb C = \Bbb R[i] \cong \Bbb R[X]/(X^2\!+1)\:$ where $\ i := x =  X + (X^2\!+1).\:$ Then $$\: i^2\!+1\, =\, x^2\!+1\, =\, h(X)\,h(X)+1\, =\, h(X^2)+h(1) \,=\, h(X^2\!+1)\, =\, 0$$

because $\, h\, $ is a ring homomorphism. A completely analogous inductive proof works when we replace $\, X^2\!+1\,$ by an arbitrary polynomial $\,P(X)\,$ because  a polynomial is composed of basic ring operations plus and times, which are preserved by $\,h,\,$ as are the "coefficients" (i.e. the elements of the base ring $\,F).\:$  This yields your statement (a fundamental theorem of Kronecker).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing $F[x] = F[X]/(f(X))$, so the described map sends each polynomial in $F[X]$ to it's equivalence class in $F[x]$, that is, for all $p(X) \in F[X]$,

$$p(X) \mapsto p(X) +(f(X))$$

Comment: This was my thought as well. Thus, $f(X) \mapsto f(X) + (f(X)) = (f(X))$, the zero in $f(X)/(f(X))$.

Comment: Correction: ...the zero in $F[X]/(f(X))$

Comment: $F[x]$ should mean the subring of $F[X]/(f(X))$ generated by $F$ and $x$. (of course, thus does turn out to be equal to all of $F[X]/(f(X))$)

Answer (score 1):

The notation is indeed peculiar. I am guessing that they are using $P$ as a variable to denote an arbitrary polynomial operation (with coefficients in $F$), so that $P(X)$ is an element of $F[X]$, and $P(x)$ is an element of $F[X] / (f(X))$ (and, incidentally, is a member of the subring $F[x]$).

If all they said was $P(X) \mapsto P(x)$, I wouldn't have given this interpretation a second thought. If they described is a map

$$ F[X] \to F[x] : P(X) \mapsto P(x)$$

(to be read as "a map from $F[X]$ to $F[x]$ that sends $P(X)$ to $P(x)$) I wouldn't give this interpretation a second thought either. I don't think I've ever seen this written in the way you've quoted, though.

Comment: Precisely what do you think is "peculiar". The notation looks standard to me.

Comment: @MathGems: As I said in my last sentence. I don't think I've ever seen before somebody write

$$\text{Definition of function : Domain -> Codomain}$$

The closest I've seen is the function expressed arithmetically, e.g. things like

$$ g \circ f : A \to B$$

Comment: Yes, I agree that is a bit peculiar (but probably not the key stumbling block, since that denotation is easily inferred). Sometimes it is written in that order with a comma (vs. colon), so it might simply be a typo for that.

Comment: @MathGems: With varying degrees of "easily"; we have an advantage knowing that the quotient map is the obvious thing to be talking about here, even if the OP were to completely omit (*), and the experience to be confident in that assessment. :)

Comment: Indeed, the ease of inference of a unique denotation may be complicated by other points not well understood (which are not clear just yet).

Answer (score 0):

Well, at least the fact that $P(X)$ denoted a generic polynomial I have guessed (in previous indications of the text are never used capital letters). I admit I was out of the way with my interpretation, so thank you very much for the detailed explanation. Hence $h$ is the evaluation homomorphism from $F[X]$ to quotient ring (this thing I did not really think, failing to interpret $F[x]$), at which point the implied operation is simple enough.

The fact is that I'm trying to expand my knowledge in abstract algebra, being at the current time at a level of basic knowledge: Hernstein's manual and another text a little more advanced which, however, to understand the level, will quote only the theorem of existence of algebraically closed extensions.

Currently I would like to acquire the Galois theory in its generality, and other topics, and through a text found on the web, presupposing certain knowledge (which in principle think I have), I have reached, through the references, the text of Dummit and Foote. Just today I got a copy and I think it's a great text covering all the topics I want to explore.

I take this opportunity and ask you if you know a better text (I'm going to buy the Dummit's book). For example, the evaluation map Math Gems mentions appears (uniqueness apart) on the second book that I mentioned, in relation to the chapter on the fields theory. In Hernstein (far as I remember) there is no trace, but I must to precise that in reading, I skipped a lot of exercises. I do not remember the notation $F[x]$ in these two books, and even less a detalied argumentation as that of MathGems. Indeed, the second one uses that notation just to denote $F[X]$. Of course, a not univocal symbolism sometimes creates a beautiful mess! :-)